# Simple javascript staff training questionnaire

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create a page for my staff to train them. Basically each question is multiple choice, if they check a radio box they get a small notice like a  showing below stating "correct" or "incorrect".

At the very bottom of the page is the last  that only shows when all the above questions are answered correctly.

Can I get any suggestions/examples on how to achieve this?

Key Notes:

- I'm trying to make this as simple as I can to show my staff what to
  do. The info and answers I will explain above for each question
  directly above them, so the javascript (or what ever you suggest)
  doesn't have to be complex or well hidden.
- I'm using Squarespace, so I have access to html, java, (page header code), css, as well as header/footer code injection for the template i use

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @Andy -_- your absolutely right. I've edited to actually ask a question..

Answer (score 2):

when I have a simple task to achieve with radio buttons I like to skip using javascript and instead listen to css pseudo-classes. Example:

css:

```
.correct_answer {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.correct:checked ~ .correct_answer {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

html:

```
<div>
  <p id=question1>What is the teacher's favorite color?</p>
  <input type=radio class=correct name=question1 /> blue
  <br>
  <input type=radio name=question1 /> red
  <br>
  <input type=radio name=question1 /> green
  <p class=correct_answer>Correct!</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id=question2>What month is independence day on?</p>
  <input type=radio name=question2 /> january
  <br>
  <input type=radio class=correct name=question2 /> july
  <br>
  <input type=radio name=question2 /> december
  <p class=correct_answer>Correct!</p>
</div>
```

How it works? The ~ (sibling) operator tells the paragraph to show when the correct answer is in checked state. The name attribute on radio buttons makes them exclude each other as selected answers. The divs are just to separate some elements from others to avoid the ~ operator to match correct answers from other questions.

the best is, no javascript :) simpler impossible.

See the live example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zw0ptyu2/

---

But if you really want javascript here is the same example using jQuery (see the fiddle too here: https://jsfiddle.net/rtc6ygkz/).

The idea is, instead of using css pseudo-class, use an actual class that is added and removed by jQuery.

css:

```
.correct_answer {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.correct_answer.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

html: stays the same.

javascript (requires jQuery):

```
$("[type=radio]").change(function(){
    var correct_answer = $(this).parent().find(".correct_answer");
    if ($(this).is(".correct")) {
      correct_answer.addClass("active");
    } else {
      correct_answer.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: note that to have the text also activate their corresponding radio button you could simply enclose it in a label with attribute 'for' having same value as an 'id' attribute of the corresponding input element. I have decided not to include this in the answer for simplicity's sake.

Comment: In this case, I think it would be more accessible to use display: block instead of visibility: visible. I believe visibility hidden just hides it from the eye, but I think screen readers will still pick up on it. You don't want them finding the answer too early ;).

Comment: you are right, it depends on taste too, I don't like when elements push other elements around because they became visible, this is the advantage of visibility.

Comment: Agreed. I suppose you could enter the text "answer goes here", and then use javascript to change it to "correct" and to make it visible when the proper radio button is selected...but then it's not as simple as your way. I'm not sure there's much we can do to avoid that, though, in order to make it accessible.

Comment: I like the non java version, it will be perfect for use in each section of the questionnaire. But how do I only show a <div> at the bottom of the page if all of the questions above are correct? I'm sorry I wasn't overly clear in the question. but for the final part, once the staff have completed the training correctly I'm wanting a form to become visible so I can log who has completed the training.